# st_distance_sphere from PostGIS returns unexpected value?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am working with PostgreSQL v9.1.11 and PostGIS 2.1.0.  I am using st_distance_sphere to calculate the distance between various points and am getting unusual results.  According to the documentation, that function should return the distance in meters between the 2 points supplied.  Here are two examples that I have run:

```
select st_distance_sphere(
  st_setsrid(st_makepoint(33.44, -82.60), 4326),  -- location near Warrenton, GA
  st_setsrid(st_makepoint(33.533, -82.517), 4326) -- locaton near Thomson, GA
)
```

which returns 9325.862 meters, or 5.8 miles, which seems correct

```
select st_distance_sphere(
  st_setsrid(st_makepoint(33.44, -82.60), 4326),  -- location near Warrenton, GA
  st_setsrid(st_makepoint(32.819, -97.361), 4326) -- location near Forth Worth, TX
)
```

which returns 9873.560 meters, or 6.1 miles, which ain't even close.

I have read and re-read the PostGIS docs and can't find anything I am doing wrong.  Is that function just misbehaving?

Comment: Ask here http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifying your queries I've obtained the following error:

[image]

Looking back in the documentation we can see this:

```
ST_Distance_Sphere — Returns linear distance in meters between two lon/la points
```

That means the first coordinate for a point must be the **longitude**, and the second the **latitude**.

Therefore you'll have the following, properly, coordinates for your locations:

```
(-82.60, 33.44)   -- location near Warrenton, GA
(-82.517, 33.533  -- locaton near Thomson, GA
(-97.361, 32.819) -- location near Forth Worth, TX
```

Now, let's run the queries again:

```sql
select st_distance_sphere(
  st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-82.60, 33.44), 4326),  -- location near Warrenton, GA
  st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-82.517, 33.533), 4326) -- locaton near Thomson, GA
)
```

**Result:** `12891.3730143974 meters` = `8.01 miles`

```sql
select st_distance_sphere(
  st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-82.60, 33.44), 4326),  -- location near Warrenton, GA
  st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-97.361, 32.819), 4326) -- location near Forth Worth, TX
)
```

**Result:** `1375107.45231354 meters` = `854.45 miles`

Comment: Thanks Sorin, knew it was something stupid on my part

Answer (score 0):

I found that using **st_point** and **geometry** is a way to do this:

```
select ST_Distance_Sphere(st_point(lng_1, lat_1)::geometry
                         ,st_point(lng_2, lat_2)::geometry) as distance
```

And worked for data stored at my DB, greetings!